# Как идентифицировать участников сети на одной машине?

Tags: сервер, ip, сеть, tcp-ip

Допустим, есть желание научить общаться по сети клиентские приложения через сервер, который и будет заниматься рассылкой сообщений. Ок, все понятно, у каждого клиента будет IP-адрес и порт, он будет слушать порт и получать сообщения. Но что если и клиенты и сервер находятся на одной машине? Как их идентифицировать, ведь IP у всех один и тот же? Дать каждому по своему порту? Есть более удобные способы?

Comment: Вы в любом случае физически на одном ip не сможете запустить два приложения, слушающих один и тот же порт. так что порты полюбому разные будут

Comment: @Mike да, а вы ведь правы, ответ, в общем-то, лежал на поверхности. Дополнительная идентификация попросту не нужна, учитывая, что порты в любом случае будут у каждого клиента разные. (P.S. оформите в виде ответа, а не комментария, иначе я не смогу отметить ваш вопрос как верный)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Порты в протоколах tcp/udp сделаны как раз для идентификации конечных приложений в пределах одного IP адреса. На одном IP физически невозможно запустить два приложения слушающих один и тот же порт. При подключении приложения в режиме клиента ОС сама назначает ему некий уникальный порт. Так что для идентификации клиента связки ip:порт вполне достаточно.

Comment: может вы дадите рекомендации по выбору портов, ведь выбирать порт нужно осторожно чтобы не занят случайно порт, который может понадобится системному приложению или какому-то популярному. Существует какой-то безопасный диапазон портов, чтобы быть уверенным, что разрабатываемое приложение не вызовет проблем?

Comment: @YesMan https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_TCP_%D0%B8_UDP  думаю они постарались все часто используемые туда включить. Обратите внимание, порты до 1024 - привелигерованные, в ОС *nix их могут использовать только процесы работающие под рутом