# Идентификация клиента. Сети

Tags: delphi, сеть

Как определить идентификационные данные клиента и на что можно ориентироваться при connect/disconnect. Объясню. Есть сервер который имеет белый ip. К нему через интернет подключаются пользователи . Пользователи наверняка могут подключаться из одной подсети и я так понимаю у них будет один ip. На что можно ориентироватся чтобы определить пользователя? Сервер на Delphi , компонетны TSocketserver, TClientSocet

Comment: А что значит идентификационные данные ? Все что вам согласится передать клиент то и использовать. Пока клиент вам явно не передаст что либо о себе типа имени и пароля у вас на руках только ip и номер порта (случайный) с которого он пришел

Comment: А что по поводу дисконнекта? Правильно ли я понимаю ,что поодьщователи из одной подсети имеют один ip? И допустим кто то из них отключился. Как зная только ip узнать какой именно . Может hostname или еще что то из отключенного сокета можно получить?

Comment: Пользователи могут быть как с одним ip, так и с разными, как провайдер решит. Но когда у двух пользователей один IP то опираться можно только на номер порта. Он для того и придуман. Связка IP-порт уникальна в любой момент времени. И для коннекта вы всегда можете получить номер порта клиента. И когда у клиентов IP один ничего более вы не узнаете, пока клиент сам это явно не сообщит

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503176/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5/503401#503401

Comment: @Mike , оформите как ответ пожалуйста. я думаю это то , что мне нужно.

Comment: Проще как дубль закрыть. Отличий от того вопроса/ответа практически нет

Comment: Как порт может идентифицировать пользователя? По какому порту подключился Петя, по какому Катя? Кто знает? Таким образом с одинаковым успехом можно "идентифицировать" по объекту Socket: TCustomWinSocket, который поступает в обработчики событий в качестве параметра. Для каждого клиента будет свой TCustomWinSocket, отличный от других. До портов даже опускаться не надо. А для настоящей идентификации надо реализовать например подключение к серверу по имени и паролю.